# How to Get Specific Array Element Values

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

This is the Sample Array that I Have:

```
$my_array = Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => Seasons:
    [2] => Winter
    [3] => Spring
    [4] => Summer
    [5] => Fall
    [6] => 
    [7] => Color List:
    [8] => Blue
    [9] => Green
    [10] => Yellow
    [11] => Cyan
    [12] => Red 
    [13] => 
    [14] => Showing the Following Fruits:
    [15] => Kiwi
    [16] => Apple
    [17] => Banana
    [18] => Mango
    [19] => Watermelon
    [20] => Orange
)
```

The Output that I wanted is like this:

Example Output:

If it saw the word "Fruits" it will only print out the array element numbers 14 to 20

```
Showing the Following Fruits:
Kiwi
Apple
Banana
Mango
Watermelon
Orange
```

If it saw the word "Color" it will print out array element numbers 7 up to 20 which is end of the array

```
Color List:
Blue
Green
Yellow
Cyan
Red 

Showing the Following Fruits:
Kiwi
Apple
Banana
Mango
Watermelon
Orange
```

What is the best way to get this output?

However I do not know how to get the value of my index. Which is in my first example is the element number 14

While researching I have seen that some people use array_search for you to get the value of the element of the array.

```
$searchval = array_search("Showing the Following Fruits:",array_values($retval));
```

However, the above code requires you to input the complete value of the array[14].

Is there anyway where I could input "**Fruits**" instead of "**Showing the Following Fruits:**" value?

Kindly see my code below:

```
for ($i = $searchval; $i <= count($my_array); $i++)
{
    echo "<pre>".$my_array[$i]."</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Take a step back and look at creating your data in a more logical way. Currently the data is to all intent and purpose unusable

Comment: Your second example violates the rule that you declare above the first example 'If it saw the word "Fruits" it will _only_ print out the array element numbers 14 to 20' (emphasis mine).  "Fruits" is in the second example, but you are printing _more_ than lines 14 to 20.

Comment: Just use a multidimensional  array and loop through the values with a foreach loop.

Comment: Hi Guy's thank you for all the comments. I have edited my question and added my code

Answer (score 1):

Do a while loop checking for you key words then reading all strings until hitting the next empty value.

Comment: This is not an answer! At best it is a comment!!

Comment: Can't comment yet ^^ Sorry

Comment: @Alexander This method could still be improved with a foreach loop and break whenever empty value is hit.

Comment: _Can't comment yet_ Ever thought there was a reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a multidimensional array and loop through it with a foreach loop. For example the following:

```
<?php
$array = array("Seasons" => array(1 => "Winter", 2 => "Spring", 3 => "Summer", 4 => "Fall"));

echo "Seasons:\n";
foreach ($array["Seasons"] as $season) {
    echo $season . "\n";
}
?>
```

Will return:

```
Seasons:
Winter
Spring
Summer
Fall
```

Edit:

Alternatively if you're wanting to maintain your current array format you could instead use a foreach loop and check the values of the key in the array before returning the element. For example this:

```
<?php
$my_array = Array
(
    1 => "Seasons:",
    2 => "Winter",
    3 => "Spring",
    4 => "Summer",
    5 => "Fall",
    6 => " ",
    7 => "Color List:",
    8 => "Blue",
    9 => "Green",
    10 => "Yellow",
    11 => "Cyan",
    12 => "Red",
    13 => " ",
    14 => "Showing the Following Fruits:",
    15 => "Kiwi",
    16 => "Apple",
    17 => "Banana",
    18 => "Mango",
    19 => "Watermelon",
    20 => "Orange"
);

foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key >= 7 && $key <= 12) {
        echo $value . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Will return this:

```
Color List:
Blue
Green
Yellow
Cyan
Red
```